# Variable unreachable for no reason (error type)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following code:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: {
    for i in 0 ..< labels.count {
        var label = labels[i]
        label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

At that point there is no compilation error. If under `label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity` I add `label` and press `Ctrl+Space` to get the autocompletion, I get this type for `label`: `<<error type>>` as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

If I try to press `Ctrl+Space` right after `label` in `label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity` I got the same `<<error type>>` even though there is no compilation error.

It tried to quit Xcode, remove all the DerivedData subdirectories but didn't change a thing.

What is the problem? Why can't I get my `label` variable? Why is it okay with `.transform` but not `.removeFromSuperView()`?

I'm probably missing something but can't figure it out.

EDIT:

Snippet to try in playground:

```
let label1 = UILabel()
let label2 = UILabel()
let labels = [label1, label2]
let test = label1

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: {
        for i in 0 ..< labels.count {
            var label = labels[i]
            label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }
        }, completion: nil)
```

Here is how I get my `labels`:

```
// displayView is a UIView where are other UIView and the UILabels 
var views = displayView.subviews as! [UIView]
views.removeRange(0...1)
let labels = views as! [UILabel]
```

Comment: try with `var label: UILabel = labels[i]` instead of `var label = labels[i]`

Comment: ... I didn't think to use that. Thanks! But how come it is not inferred? I meant it is somehow as when I check the type of `label` I get `UILabel``

Comment: @Nico how is `labels` defined?

Comment: @Fogmeister `let labels = views as! [UILabel]`

Comment: @Nico but views is not `[UILabel]` it is `[UIView]` you can't just cast like that.

Comment: I think your problem is with labels. Try using `self.labels.count` and `self.labels[i]`

Comment: Yes it is. There were some `UIView` and `UILabel` but I removed the `UIView` so now there are only `UILabel`

Comment: I added a snippet to try in playground.

Comment: @Nico That snippet compiles fine, what is the issue?

Comment: Check the screenshot I put. The type of `label` is `<<error type>>`

Comment: @Nico Ok, but the snippet doesn't reproduce that problem, so the issue must be elsewhere in your code. Since the snippet includes the declaration of `labels` and your screenshot above doesn't, we have to assume it's related to the declaration of `labels` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Stuart Well the snippet reproduce that problem for me so I guess the problem is (one more time? ;) ) xcode... I cannot reboot my laptop yet so I'll try later. I just updated the question to show you how I get my labels

Comment: @Nico Ok sorry, that is strange behaviour indeed. Does the problem persist if you use `for label in labels { ... }` instead?

Comment: Didn't really try as I need `i` to add some keyFrames but doing `var label: UILabel = labels[i]` like Akhilrajtr suggested works. I just don't understand why.

Comment: Very strange. As an aside, you can use `for (index, label) in enumerate(labels) { ... }` as a concise way to use both the array element and the index inside the loop.

Comment: I forgot that one. I'll use it straight away! Thanks